# Codenameone - TextField & Keyboard

Tags: codenameone

I have problem with my TextField for getting user's input. I followed examples available (developer guide, stackoverflow etc etc), but somehow the keyboard doesn't appear. Attached is the code ( I deleted the rest of my codes for t'shooting purposes) & the screenshot.

Need help on how can I make the virtual keyboard appear.

TQ in advance.[image: TextField without keyboard]

```
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.TextField;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a     href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the         purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class celebriesta {

private Form current;
private Resources theme;
private Form home, allEvent, specEvent, picEvent;


public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

    // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

    // Pro only feature
    Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
}

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
  }

        home = new Form("Home", BoxLayout.y());
        home.setScrollableY(true);

        TextField txt = new TextField();
        txt.setFocusable(true);
        txt.setConstraint(TextField.NUMERIC);
        txt.startEditingAsync();

        home.addComponent(txt); 
        home.show();
 }


public void stop() {
    current = getCurrentForm();
}

public void destroy() {
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard doesn't appear in the simulator. Just use your computers keyboard to type into the text field.

When running on the device the native OS virtual keyboard will appear as expected.